# Equivalent of @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="foo") over an external Properties object?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

The CustomProperties object is in an external library, so I cannot add the annotation, but I still would like to feed it from my Spring Boot YAML by means of a prefix.

Comment: How are you initializing `CustomProperties` class? Does this class have `@Component or @Service` annotation on it?

Comment: Still did not do it, im just assessing how to attack it, ideally I would save myself to replicate and convert the CustomProperties class in my Boot domain app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

In the @Configuration:

```
  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties("company.custom")
  public CustomProperties customProperties(){
    return new CustomProperties();
  }
```